# Adding service reference wcf

Tags: wcf

The issue has already discussed here, but it did not addressed it quite the way I  am looking for.

I have already created a service reference from a client console app in visual studio, but I want to do it programmatically with the following contraint:

From [Microsoft Docs - wcf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/client-app-discovery-proxy-to-find-a-service), it obvious that we have to have the service interface reference available to the client. In my case I do have the reference available, instead I have the address where the service is hosted and this address is a dynamic one.

So I want to define a customized client class that will have its object declared with the host address only. Lets take the following snippet as an example:

```
public partial class CalculatorServiceClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<ICalculatorService>, ICalculatorService  
{  

}
```

As you can see that ICalculatorService is available while defining the class. What to do if the interface to the service is not available while defining the class.

Comment: Have you found your answer yet?

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to the WCF service pragmatically without having to use the generated class methods, but note that this can have issues if the service changes in future

The idea is simple .

Create a service contract that matches your service implementation

```
[DataContract]
public class SomeDataContarctClass
{
   [DataMember]
   public string SomeMember{get;set;}
   etc....
}
```

Create the interface

```
public IServiceInterface
{
    [OperationContract]
    List<SomeDataContarctClass> GetSomeData();
    ...etc
}
```

Now this is where you start to Glue things together,

**Then create the service**

```
public IServiceInterface CreateIService()
        {
            EndpointAddress myEndpoint = new EndpointAddress("SERVICE URL");
            BasicHttpBinding binding= new BasicHttpBinding();
                defaultBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647;
                defaultBinding.MaxBufferPoolSize = 2147483647;
                defaultBinding.MaxBufferSize = 2147483647;
                defaultBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = 2147483647;
                defaultBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = 2147483647;
            ChannelFactory<IUpdaterService> myChannelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IServiceInterface>(binding, myEndpoint);
            myChannelFactory.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new ServiceInterceptionBehavior());
            // Create a channel.
            return myChannelFactory.CreateChannel();
        }
```

Then you can call the service using

```
var myserviceImp = CreateIService();
var data = myserviceImp.GetSomeData();
```

Comment: The service will change. What I am looking for is the coded forms of the stuff we do while adding service reference from the client. You have noticed that we only provide the address where are service is hosted, then we press go and we get everything that is necessary.

Comment: SO you want to be able to generate the client from WSDL on the fly?